# Tokenization, Lexical Analysis, BNF, Context Free Grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, bnf, lexical

I just want to ask if Tokenization is the same as Lexical analysis and if Backus Naur Form is the same as Context Free Grammar? I need to define and explain all four and give examples but It seems some websites treat some as one.

Thank you.

Comment: extra question: Can I name my tokens anything? like the = sign. Can I call it "equal operator" or "operator equal" or is there a strict token for that that I need to follow?

Answer (score 2):

*Tokenization* and *lexical analysis* are synonyms. Backus-Naur form is a language or notation for *describing* context-free grammars; thus, it is not correct to say that Backus-Naur form *is* a context-free grammar.

Edit: Corrected my statement after @Gunther's comment below.

Comment: BNF is for context-free grammars. There is a single nonterminal on the left hand side of each production. You need to lift this restriction for expressing context-sensitive grammars, and you won't call that BNF.

Comment: @Gunther: I actually wasn't aware of that restriction; thanks!

Comment: extra question: Can I name my tokens anything? like the = sign. Can I call it "equal operator" or "operator equal" or is there a strict token for that that I need to follow?

Comment: @Levi: You choose all token names yourself; however, you must define what each of them means: `<equal_operator> ::= "="`.

Comment: @Levi: Regardless of how you think a token is named, the ways you can specify them to a tool is determined by the tool.  Pick a tool (e.g, Flex) and read the rules about what you can say.